# Class HW Help C++

Tags: c++

I am creating this program for my class homework.I cannot figure out why I am not getting the correct value for lowest minimum amount of rainfall, I keep getting 0. I believe I am not assigning it the correct value. Any help would be great!
 Thanks!

```
enter code here
#include <iomanip>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std; 

double Average_Rain(double, double);




 int main ()
 {
double total, average, months, min =0, max = 0;
months = 12.00;



double rainAmount[12];

min == rainAmount[0];
max == rainAmount[0];


for (int i = 0; i < 12; i++){

    cout << "Enter the inches of rain for month " << i + 1 << ":" << endl;
    cin >> rainAmount[i];

            while (rainAmount[i] < 0){
            cout << "Sorry the amount of rain for the month cannot be less than 0." << endl;
            cout << endl;
            cout << "Re-enter the inches of rain this month. " << endl;
            cin >> rainAmount[i];
            }

                if (min > rainAmount[i])

                    min = rainAmount[i];

                    if (max < rainAmount[i])

                        max = rainAmount[i];

                        total += rainAmount[i];

}
                    average = Average_Rain(total,months);
                    cout << "The totlal amount of rain for the year was " << setprecision(2) << fixed << total << " inches." << endl;
                    cout << setprecision(2) << "The total average of rain fall for the year was " << average << " inches." << endl;
                    cout << "The smallest amount of rain was " << min << " inches." << endl;
                    cout << "The largest amount of rain was " << max << " inches." << endl;


      }

       double Average_Rain(double total, double months){
   return total / months;
       }
```

Comment: use a debugger to see what's going on. the two intended initializations of min and max are in fact comparisons (using ==) with disregarded result, so that should not matter as they retain their assigned value 0. but min will never be greater than any positive vlaue of rainAmount, so this if never happens! please consider getting your indentation right for better readability.

Comment: @CeeMcSharpface fun fact: fixing that erroneous `==` would result in undefined behaviour as `rainAmount` is unintialized at that point.

Comment: @YSC It's UB either way.

Comment: @Bessie yes obviously, my phrasing was silly

Comment: Ohhh ok, I get what your saying.  Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <iomanip>
#include <iostream>
#include <limits>

using namespace std;  // usually this is bad to globaly use namespaces !

inline double Average_Rain(double total, double months){
    return total / months;
}

int main () {

    double total = 0; // need to be initialized !
    double min = std::numeric_limits<double>::max(), max = std::numeric_limits<double>::lowest();  // need to be initialized properly !
    const double months = 12.00;

    double rainAmount[12];

    // min == rainAmount[0]; // do nothing 
    // max == rainAmount[0]; // do nothing 

    for (int i = 0; i < 12; i++) {

        cout << "Enter the inches of rain for month " << i + 1 << ":" << endl;
        cin >> rainAmount[i];

        while (rainAmount[i] < 0 ){
            cout << "Sorry the amount of rain for the month cannot be less than 0." << endl;
            cout << endl;
            cout << "Re-enter the inches of rain this month. " << endl;
            cin >> rainAmount[i];
         }

        if (min > rainAmount[i])
            min = rainAmount[i];

        if (max < rainAmount[i])
            max = rainAmount[i];

        total += rainAmount[i];
    }

    double average = Average_Rain(total,months);
    cout << "The totlal amount of rain for the year was " << setprecision(2) << fixed << total << " inches." << endl;
    cout << setprecision(2) << "The total average of rain fall for the year was " << average << " inches." << endl;
    cout << "The smallest amount of rain was " << min << " inches." << endl;
    cout << "The largest amount of rain was "  << max << " inches." << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

[Run-able Code](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/fece58ef41c190fc)

Comment: Thank you for your help! We have not learned about limits quite yet, but it definitely seems like the best option.